# Installing tar/tar.gz packages with npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, tar.gz

My firewall blocks all *.tar.gz files from being downloaded.
I need to manually whitelist all websites from which I download *.tar.gz files.

I cannot find which URL I should whitelist to download packages using `npm`.

Could you please help me on that?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you download the packages?

Comment: I simply run `npm install`. I have already whitelisted https://www.npmjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: allow all traffic to https://registry.npmjs.org/